# How do you draw 3D text on iOS using UIKit or Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

Are there any techniques that would allow drawing real 3D text (not the fake kind where you draw the text over and over) using UIKit or Core Graphics? I can rotate and transform a UILabel but the text is flat and has no depth...

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully iOS 8 will have [Scene Kit](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/16/#scene-kit). But until then, your only option is to use OpenGL ES, or a third party library providing an OOP wrapper around OpenGL ES.